# Using templates to conditionally generate data members of a C++ class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a class that works as a set of integers in some fixed range
0 ... n and can easily deal with adding a new element, removing an element, emptying the set and checking if an integer is part of the set. The code of the class is followed.

Also, as can be seen in the code, if option `COMPUTE_SET_SIZE` is present, the class computes the size of the set and, if option `COMPUTE_LINKED_LIST` is present, one can use the class to efficiently enumerate set elements.

Now, the problem is that enumerating set elements is a heavy operation in terms of memory usage and, lots of the time, it's not needed. Therefore, I want to somehow be able to generate those parts of the code only when they are needed without having to maintain two different classes (one with this functionality and one without).

I understand that templates (such as std::enable_if) can be used to achieve similar goals but I fail to understand how I can use them to conditionally generate data members such as prev and next in the following code.

```
#ifndef _FIXED_SIZE_INT_SET_H_
#define _FIXED_SIZE_INT_SET_H_

#include <cstring>

#include <assert.h>

#define COMPUTE_SET_SIZE
#define COMPUTE_LINKED_LIST

class FixedSizeIntSet
{
    private:
        const int MAX_TAG = 1000000000;
        int capacity;
        int currentTag;
        int *tags;

#ifdef COMPUTE_SET_SIZE
        int size;
#endif

#ifdef COMPUTE_LINKED_LIST
        int start;
        int *next;
        int *prev;
#endif

        void initialize() { memset(tags, 0, capacity * sizeof(int)); }
    public:
        FixedSizeIntSet(int capacity)
        {
            this->capacity = capacity;
            this->currentTag = 1;
            tags = new int[capacity];

#ifdef COMPUTE_SET_SIZE
            size = 0;
#endif

#ifdef COMPUTE_LINKED_LIST
            start = -1;
            next = new int[capacity];
            prev = new int[capacity];
#endif

            initialize();
        }

        void insert(int n)
        {
            assert((n >= 0) && (n < capacity));
#ifdef COMPUTE_SET_SIZE
            if (tags[n] != currentTag) size++;
#endif
#ifdef COMPUTE_LINKED_LIST
            if (tags[n] != currentTag)
            {
                next[n] = start;
                prev[n] = -1;
                if (start >= 0)
                    prev[start] = n;
                start = n;
            }
#endif
            tags[n] = currentTag;
        }
        void remove(int n)
        {
            if ((n >= 0) && (n < capacity))
            {
#ifdef COMPUTE_SET_SIZE
                if (tags[n] == currentTag) size--;
#endif
#ifdef COMPUTE_LINKED_LIST
                if (tags[n] == currentTag)
                {
                    if (next[n] >= 0)
                        prev[next[n]] = prev[n];
                    if (prev[n] >= 0)
                        next[prev[n]] = next[n];
                    else
                        start = next[n];
                }
#endif
                tags[n] = 0;
            }
        }
        void clear()
        {
            if (currentTag < MAX_TAG)
                currentTag++;
            else { initialize(); currentTag = 1; }
#ifdef COMPUTE_SET_SIZE
            size = 0;
#endif
#ifdef COMPUTE_LINKED_LIST
            start = -1;
#endif
        }

        bool hasMember(int n) { return ((n >= 0) && (n < capacity)) ? (currentTag == tags[n]) : false; }

#ifdef COMPUTE_LINKED_LIST
        int begin() { return start; }
        int end() { return -1; }
        int nextNumber(int curNumber) { assert((curNumber >= 0) && (curNumber < capacity)); return next[curNumber]; }
#endif
};

#endif
```

Ideally, I would like a code like this:

```
template <bool enableEnumeration>
class FixedSizeIntSet {
  ....
}
```

So that `FixedSizeIntSet<false>` does not compute linked list (and does not have associated data members) while `FixedSizeIntSet<true>` computes linked lists.

Comment: Define switchable behaviours in base classes (CRTP can be useful), then inherit conditionally.

Comment: Simple: Use no template, have two distinct classes.

Comment: @Quentin: Thanks for the CRTP reference. I didn't know anything about it. I read a little bit on it from Wikipedia but I cannot see the relation. Can you elaborate more (or, if possible, put an answer)?

Comment: A 32x memory overhead cost, in exchange you get O(1) clear, seems very questionable.  32x the memory will make your code much, much slower.  I guess if you keep on setting 13 values out of 1,000,000 then clearing, it could pay off, but...

Comment: @Yakk: In my case, this more than pays off! This is based on the results of profiling my code which uses this set right in its heart. The set gets cleared very often and it is actually true that it usually contains very few elements from a large domain. Also, since you're implying using bits instead of int's, it would not just affect clearing time. It would also increase time of insert an element and/or test its membership to the set because of the arithmetic involved. While still O(1), I would assume that it would still make my runtime go sky high.

Comment: @Shahab I would be very surprised if the arithmetic operations would be anywhere near as expensive as cache misses, and reducing memory size by a factor of 32 should usually reduce cache misses.  Similarly, an optimal solution where we use the page table to zero stuff instead of memory access would make zeroing roughly a million times faster than a naive loop over memory.  Reads to zeroed pages could be serviced without actually getting the page, just the page table entry, so would also be faster.  Something to think about.

Comment: @Yakk Thinking about cache misses versus arithmetic is an interesting point. I would try it to see how it plays out. As I said, this is right in the heart of the program and I could at least say that I saved 50% of the time by just changing it from hash sets to this structure but I will certainly try bit vectors as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to address your design problem.

Definition of the class.

```
#ifndef _FIXED_SIZE_INT_SET_H_
#define _FIXED_SIZE_INT_SET_H_

#include <cstring>

#include <assert.h>

template <typename Trait>
class FixedSizeIntSet : public Trait
{
    private:
        const int MAX_TAG = 1000000000;
        int capacity;
        int currentTag;
        int *tags;

        void initialize() { memset(tags, 0, capacity * sizeof(int)); }
    public:
        FixedSizeIntSet(int capacity) : Trait(capacity)
        {
            this->capacity = capacity;
            this->currentTag = 1;
            tags = new int[capacity];
            initialize();
        }

        void insert(int n)
        {
            assert((n >= 0) && (n < capacity));
            if (tags[n] != currentTag)
            {
               Trait::insert();
            }
            tags[n] = currentTag;
        }
        void remove(int n)
        {
            if ((n >= 0) && (n < capacity))
            {
                if (tags[n] == currentTag) 
                {
                   Trait::remove(n);
                }
                tags[n] = 0;
            }
        }
        void clear()
        {
            if (currentTag < MAX_TAG)
                currentTag++;
            else { initialize(); currentTag = 1; }
            Trait::clear();
        }

        bool hasMember(int n) { return ((n >= 0) && (n < capacity)) ? (currentTag == tags[n]) : false; }
};

#endif
```

Usage:

```
struct ComputeSetSize
{
   ComputeSetSize(int ) : size(0) {}
   void insert(int ) { ++size; }
   void remove(int ) { --size; }
   void clear() { size = 0; }
   int size;
};

struct ComputeLinkedList
{
   ComputeLinkedList(int capacity)
   {
      start = -1;
      next = new int[capacity];
      prev = new int[capacity];
   }

   void insert(int n)
   {
      next[n] = start;
      prev[n] = -1;
      if (start >= 0)
         prev[start] = n;
      start = n;
   }

   void remove(int n)
   {
      if (next[n] >= 0)
         prev[next[n]] = prev[n];
      if (prev[n] >= 0)
         next[prev[n]] = next[n];
      else
         start = next[n];
   }

   void clear()
   {
      start = -1;
   }

   int begin() { return start; }
   int end() { return -1; }
   int nextNumber(int curNumber) { assert((curNumber >= 0) && (curNumber < capacity)); return next[curNumber]; }

   int capacity;
   int size;
   int start;
   int *next;
   int *prev;
};


int main()
{
   FixedSizeIntSet<ComputeSetSize> set1(10);
   FixedSizeIntSet<ComputeLinkedList> set2(20);
}
```

Comment: Minor precision : this is Mixin, the opposite of CRTP. Mixin inherits from its parameter, CRTP has its parameter inherit from it.